# Read values auto update UWA/UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
private async void CharacteristicReadButton_Click()
{
    // BT_Code: Read the actual value from the device by using Uncached.
    GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
    if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        string formattedResult = FormatValueByPresentation(result.Value, presentationFormat);
        rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read result: {formattedResult}", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        rootPage.NotifyUser($"Read failed: {result.Status}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

I'm facing a problem with the read value change. I have setup mpu5060 with my rfduino, so whenever my rfduino moved, it will display the angle on my Arduino serial monitor.

for my c#, I can read the value when I press the "read" button. But if my value(angle) change, it will not auto update to notify user. I have to manually click the "read" button again to change. **How do I make it auto update ?**

Answer (score 1):

you need to create timer thread to monitor changing of your value.

see this
[Timer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks. I will try and update you in a few minutes time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting up your RfDuino to send a notification, if that is possible.
Or even add your data as advertising, then there is no need for a connection, just reed in in   OnAdvertisementReceived.

In your RfDuino do it like this:

```
void advertise(const char *data, uint32_t ms)
{
  // this is the data we want to appear in the advertisement
  // /make sure that the RfDuino name + data is not more than 31 bytes
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = data;

  // start the BLE stack
  RFduinoBLE.begin();

  // advertise for ms milliseconds
  RFduino_ULPDelay(ms);

  // stop the BLE stack
  RFduinoBLE.end();
}
```

If you want to send new data call:

```
// advertise "data" for indicated time
advertise("your data", duration);
```

Comment: interesting. I will try. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you ad this to your Arduino sketch. There is also a full example in the RfDuino library:  RFduino/libraries/RFduinoBLE/examples/AdvertisementPeriodic/AdvertisementPeriodic.ino

Comment: I found out theres a subscription to change button. But when I pressed it, it appears that it shows "unknown format". how do I fix this ? refer to my latest post